# Copy UIView from another UIViewController and his events

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, uiview, uiviewcontroller

my project i'm building 5 same page but **only the content change**.
So in my **AUIViewController** i can switch page **like TabBarController** and get the view that i selected by the **SegmentedControl**. The problem is that event and function that i do in **GUIViewController** isn't call. it like simple view. How can i sovle that.

any answers will be appreciated :)

*code are not exactly the same but it's work.*

**AUIViewController.m :**

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  ...
  ...
  for (.. i <= 5 ..) {
   UIStoryboard      *sb   = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL]                                        
   UIViewController   *g   =  [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GController"];
   [self.content addSubView:a.view]
   [slef.viewControllers addObject:g]
  }
  UIViewController* first =  [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
  [self.content bringSubviewToFront:first.view];
}
```

**AUIViewController.h :**

```
....
@proprety (strong,nonatomic) UIView content; // it's a containair
@proprety NsMuableArray* controllerView;
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the viewController doesn't stick around.  In order to keep it and allow it to control the view, you need to add it as a childViewController.

Add this:

```
UIViewController* first =  [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[self.content bringSubviewToFront:first.view];
```

// New stuff

```
[first willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:first];
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Actually it's working it coz in the storyboard i delete and create again my GControllerView and i forgot to link trigger. Thanks again @AMayes